# OPENGL extension: GL_EXT_gpu_shader4

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

My graphics card is Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)  (0x1916) and the glxinfo shows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center     
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)     
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.1.0-devel    
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40    
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)   
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile    
OpenGL core profile extensions:   
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.1.0-devel    
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30   
OpenGL context flags: (none)   
OpenGL extensions:   
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 12.1.0-devel    
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10    
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I am developing an app that needs `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4`  extension. But my glxinfo doesn't show the extension in the list. Please help me out to get the extension.

Comment: Usually, this extensions are provided by the GPU driver. If you haven't `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4`, then your driver didn't implemented that. As you have an Intel, maybe there's no other driver. See if it has updates. You cannot obtain this extension if the driver maintainers don't implement it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849001/enabling-opengl-extensions if you are developing using OpenGL 3.0 or higher, you don't need this extension.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open your context as a core profile, not a compatability profile.

The Mesa Open Source driver base only does not support GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 in compatibility profiles, only in core profiles.

Please refer to the Mesa3D website for more info:
http://www.mesa3d.org

Comment: Update, in VERY recent Mesa versions they enabled compatibility profiles on OpenGL 4.x.  However, it is still recommended to use a core profile if you can.  

Compatibility profiles enable a lot of bulk, much of which could slow down your game's shaders, or introduce bugs into them.

Comment: Core profile does not support it either https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=3229. And compatibility profile supports GL_ARB_gpu_shader5

Comment: GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 is supported and that implies GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 is supported.  

GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 is only exposed as present when you load a shader with the appropriate shader model to apply the limit to GL_EXT_gpu_shader4  Otherwise it will show GL_EXT_gpu_shader5

Honestly, I wish this was better implemented too.  However, it isn't.  The newest supported shader model is the only one displayed.

If you want to "force" the display this extension you can do so by forcing the GLSL version of the shader testing for it.

Comment: I have a #version 120 shader that uses the GL_EXT_gpu_shader4. It fails to build on GL_RENDERER: AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.26.0, 4.18.0-13-generic, LLVM 7.0.0)
(Linux)

Comment: Created a new question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115216/amd-gl-ext-gpu-shader4-extension

Comment: #version 120 shaders imply compatibility context.
The extension in question requires #version 400